# Jquery Collapse and expand plugin for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I been using bootstrap [collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) in my site.

is there any jquery that i can use in my bootstrap site that will work like this.

**example**

i have a comment section. sample comment would be like this.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
> sit amet suscipit magna. Sed nisl ipsum, tempus quis tincidunt non,
> molestie eget tortor. Sed scelerisque magna arcu, non hendrerit lorem
> vehicula ut. Vestibulum vulputate erat non mauris vulputate
> condimentum. Nam adipiscing nec risus at condimentum. Nulla sed lorem
> lacus. Proin bibendum, diam non faucibus fringilla, diam leo
> scelerisque nisl, sed tempor velit diam eu turpis. Aenean lacinia
> auctor tellus non tincidunt. Vivamus condimentum sem lacus. Donec
> vehicula eros erat, eu scelerisque urna varius eu. Phasellus lobortis
> dignissim dolor euismod pharetra. Morbi sodales posuere nisi sodales
> adipiscing. Vestibulum nec tortor vitae diam pharetra pretium sed eget
> arcu. Vestibulum ultricies rutrum risus. Cras rhoncus magna eget
> viverra dignissim. Integer et justo lacus.

i want to make it something like this..that on every 5th of the line it will be change it to see more like the one on facebook.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
> sit amet suscipit magna. Sed nisl ipsum, tempus quis tincidunt non,
> molestie eget tortor. Sed scelerisque magna arcu, non hendrerit lorem
> vehicula ut. Vestibulum vulputate erat non mauris vulputate
> condimentum. Nam adipiscing nec risus at condimentum. Nulla sed lorem
>
> [See more...](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

i tried using collapse in bootstrap collapse but it collapse all part of the message.

Comment: http://pvdspek.github.io/jquery.autoellipsis/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`jTruncate`](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/jtruncate-text-truncation-for-jquery.html) jQuery plugin.

> In a nutshell, jTruncate provides simple yet customizable truncation
>   for text entities in your web page.

Code:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('p').jTruncate({
        moreText: "See more..."
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/wFTLj/